# Error: Attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Tags: hard-drive

Before I start, I'd like to mention a few things.
I'm quite a newbie, and do not know much about Ubuntu. All I wanted was to be able to have a dual boot Windows7/Ubuntu, the latter being a backup when my Windows get a bit slow. It's been working fine, and I have mostly been browsing on firefox with it.
I have very little knowledge of Ubuntu (I don't know how to do commands, "sudo" things etc). I've looked up my question a few times, and words such as "kernel" pop up, which confuse me.

So please, be tolerant and patient with me! :)

A few days ago, my laptop fell from the desk (cables hanging, pulled on by a foot...). I've had this laptop for over 3 years and it fell a few times (I'm very clumsy), nothing major happened to it appart from a few scuffs. Yet, since this happened, my computer seems to refuse to boot properly, and at the "Grub" ,where you select between Ubuntu and Windows, I get the error "Attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'".

If I try to boot Windows, nothing happens.

I suspect it is due to the computer falling and possibly damaging the Hard Drive, but I am not sure.
I did try and install a few programs before (such as VLC etc) while on Ubuntu, attempting at the "sudo" thingies... Could I have done something wrong to mess up the whole hard drive?

In any case, since this happened, I have not been able to boot my computer, and right now am using an old laptop to post this message.
I have a little bit of knowledge on dismantling laptops, so I removed the hard drive from the laptop and connected it to this one. It does the same error, so I confirmed (to myself) that it wasn't hardware problems of the laptop but just the Hard Drive.

Thank you for your time, and many thanks if you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost definitely seems like a hardware issue. Try making another live-boot disk or USB drive (ubuntu) and booting into that. If you can mount your hard drive (via the file manager) it isn't a hardware issue, and would be something else. However, hd0 is the name that GRUB gives to your hard drive, so if it (suddenly) doesn't see it, it's likely not due to software.

Alternatively, try booting into your BIOS and see if it can see your hard drive. Either way, I'd be surprised if it's **not** a hard drive failure.

Comment: It is the hard drive failing at the hardware level. [Data recovery might be possible](http://lifehacker.com/5982339/diy-data-recovery-tricks-for-when-your-hard-drive-goes-belly-up) but if you're not able to do it yourself [it can be very expensive](http://www.seagate.com/services-software/data-recovery-services/consumers/in-lab-data-recovery/process/). Unfortunately, unless you're willing to shell out considerable dough you're probably SOL. This would be a good time to read up [on data backup programs](https://www.google.com/search?q=data+backup+programs) for the future.

Answer (score 1):

The mere fact that you get errors after a drop, and such severe ones that makes it not boot, is a sure sign of something being very wrong.

Computer software cannot run well on "bumpy roads" and that shows.

The very best option you have is to replace all hardware.

More: There may well be small fractions in (one or more...) PCBs which show up in intermittent manner, which is really bad if you want to keep your data intact.

Video, Music and similar content might not be that important to keep 100% intact, but when the software read from storage (harddisk) doesn't read correctly - then you're on your own, you will likely see obscure and intermittent fails.

Another source of strange faults is power supply malfunction. e.g. harddisks need both 5 and 12V feeds, if 12V fails the platters will stop rotating - read/write faults will appear, even if those failures are very short. You might not notice such a failure until it is too late - when you loose data.
The end result is very similar when the 5V supply fails, that could be called "brain damage" on the behalf of a harddisk.